# The property 'Country.IdCountry' is of type 'Guid' which is not supported by the current database provider

Tags: azure, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to use EF Core in combination with Azure CosmosDB. I'm using the following configuration:

Entities:

```
public class Country
{
    public Guid IdCountry { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string PhoneCode { get; set; }
    public IdNameReference Currency { get; set; }
}

public class IdNameReference
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

EntityConfiguration class:

```
public class CountryEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Country> builder)
    {
        builder.ToContainer("Country");
        builder.HasKey(e => e.IdCountry);
        builder.HasPartitionKey(e => e.IdCountry);
        builder.HasNoDiscriminator();
        builder.Property(e => e.IdCountry).HasConversion<GuidToStringConverter>().ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasValueGenerator<GuidValueGenerator>();
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Currency).WithMany().Metadata.DependentToPrincipal.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

DbContext OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CurrencyEntityConfiguration());
}
```

And the IServiceCollection configuration:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseCosmos(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Db_ServiceEndpoint"),
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Db_AccountKey"),
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Db_DatabaseName")
    )
);
```

But I'm still getting the following error:

`The property 'Country.IdCountry' is of type 'Guid' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'`

EDIT: I forgot to specify. This happens when I try to add a new item to the context collection

I'm new in CosmosDB and also in configuration of EF this way.

Do you have an idea, where the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, I used wrong the ValueConverter.
I used

`.HasConversion<GuidToStringConversion>()`

but I had to use

`.HasConversion<string>()`

or

`.HasConversion(g => g.ToString("D"), s => new Guid(s))`

I hope it will someone :)